# Windows video player that can play from SFTP source

Tags: windows, video, media-player, sftp

I'm looking for a video player for Windows that can read videos from SFTP source (like Archos Video Player on Android).

I know that VLC can do it but you need to enter URL and authentification every time.

Comment: It would appear that you already have your answer but just don't like it. Perhaps the knowledge that SFTP stands for Secure File Transfer Protocol might help you accept it. Secure = authenticated

Comment: Yes but you can save your password. Archos Video player on Android is the good example, it shows you all your files on your server when you connect. You don't need to know the URL of each files ...

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/781581/vlc-can-i-stream-over-ssh

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use **[Kodi](http://kodi.wiki/view/Kodi)** it works great. It lets you add SFTP as a media source, so you only have to setup the connection once. Details are [explained in their wiki](http://kodi.wiki/view/SFTPS).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use software that mounts an SFTP server as a network drive in Windows. Then you can use whichever media player you like

For example [SFTP Net Drive](https://www.nsoftware.com/sftp/netdrive/); I'm sure there are others.