# Media player for Windows that can stream from a SFTP server

Tags: windows, open-source, media-player

I'm looking for a media player, that:

- Is gratis and open-source
- Is available for at least Windows
- Can stream media from a SFTP server
- Supports all file formats that MPV supports
- Smoothly plays media, unlike VLC

Hardware accelerated rendering is nice to have.

Comment: did you tried **vlc**?

Comment: @MohamedSlama: VLC can't _smoothly_ play media, at least not on my Windows laptop…

Comment: @wb9688 specs of PC?

Comment: @MichealNancarrow: My Windows laptop has an Intel Celeron N2840 and 4GB RAM, btw VLC can't smoothly play local media either, but Baka-MPlayer, which is using MPV, can smoothly play local media…

Comment: Very similar to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/36467/windows-video-player-that-can-play-from-sftp-source

Answer (score 1):

Try with kodi, it works for me: http://kodi.wiki/view/SFTP

You can also use http://www.expandrive.com/ and you will able to open the files(videos etc) like if they are on your HDD

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest downloading and installing the latest FFMPEG for your machine - this includes FFPLAY which supports just about every protocol known and just about every file format known.

- Gratis & Open Source
- Windows *and just about everything else*
- Can stream from just about anywhere
- I have yet to find a format that it can't play (other than damaged files)
- Smooth yes subject to the points below
- HW Accelerated? It depends on the combination of your platform, OS, avaialable graphics hardware and the codec that you are playing.

If it still will not play smoothly, *(Quite possible if VLC doesn't),* then consider whether the issue might be one of:

- Your network
- Your machine
- Pesky anti-virus or other background software
- Server limitations

Comment: The Windows build doesn't contain SFTP support as I'm getting the following error: `sftp://username:password@hostname/path/to/video.mkv: Protocol not found`

Comment: Btw it can't be my network, my laptop nor my server, because it works fine when I boot from a Linux live USB and play it in MPV, also it can't be background software, because it's a clean Windows 10 install with only Firefox and Office 2016…

Comment: A "clean" Windows 10 install is anything but you will have a lot of background services running - e.g. Cortana permanently listening to your microphone and a pile of other things that are turned on by default.

Comment: Cortana isn't available here, so that isn't running, btw my CPU usage is only 2% when I've no program open, so that shouldn't be a problem, but is there a FFmpeg build for Windows with SFTP support?

Comment: I have had no luck finding a pre-built one - there are comprehensive instructions for building it for yourself but it depends on the amount of time you are ready to devote to it.